# iOS Accessibility Function - Switch Control

Tags: accessibility

I have a question regarding app support for iOS's Switch Control Accessibility function. I tried to find programming guides or API to find out how to make an app usable by Switch Control but I couldnt, thus I am asking the community.

Anyway, I have an app but it is not usable by Switch Control, which will detect only the borders of the screen estate and a scroll bar. The UI button and text cannot be detected by Switch Control. I am trying to make the app accessible to users who are using Switch Control. Appreciate if I can get tips on how to make it detectable.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find more information about this? I'm on the same boat